# I already record my biometric , should I record biometric for my new visa?

Tags: uk, indonesian-citizens

I am going to UK for business trip and may apply 6 month business trip visa.
Should I record my biometric for second time even though I have already recorded my biometric last year?

Indonesian, female, 28 years.